# Error executing ruby script in docker environment

Tags: ruby, bash, docker, elasticsearch

I have a script that is supposed to just check when my elasticsearch instance/container is up and running. But there appears to be some issue with the calls, as I get the error:

`TypeError: Failed to open TCP connection to : (no implicit conversion of nil into String)`

Here is the ruby code:

```rb
class AwaitEs
  def self.call(uri)
    AwaitEs.new(uri).wait

  def initialize(uri)  
    @uri = URI.parse("#{uri}/_cluster/health")

  def wait
    status = get_status
    until VALID_STATUS.include? status
      puts 'Still waiting ...'
      sleep 5
      status = get_status
 
  def get_status
    HEADER = {'Content-Type' => 'application/json' }.freeze
    http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
    request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri, HEADER)

    begin
      res = http.request(request)
    rescue Errno:ECONNREFUSED
      return 'red'
    end

    result = JSON.parse(response.body)
    result['status']

  private

  attr_reader :uri

  VALID_STATUS = %w[yellow green].freeze

AwaitEs.call ARGV[0]
```

The error occurs on the line `res = http.request(request)`. It appears that there is no host or port information. But when I check `uri.host=elasticsearch` and `uri.port=9200`, where `elasticsearch` is the name of the docker service for ES. When I change the host to `localhost`, the error disappears, but instead I get Connection refused instead (because the `waiter` docker does not see the elasticsearch docker on localhost.

The docker container calls the ruby script using a shell script named `start.sh`

```sh
#!/bin/sh
for file in `ls ./??_*.rb`; do
  ruby $file `http://elasticsearch:9200`
done
```

The docker-compose.yml:

```yaml
volumes:
  es_data: {}

services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: elasticsearch:5.4.3
    ports: ['9200:9200', '9300:9300']
    volumes:
      - es_data:/usr/share/elsticsearch/data
  waiter:
    build:
      context: ./waiter/
```

Finally the dockerfile for waiter:

```
FROM jruby:9.1.15-alpine
ADD ./ /app/
WORKDIR /app
CMD bash -c "./start.sh"
```

When I run this, I get the error:

Comment: In the `get_status` method, `uri` isn't obviously defined; do you need an `attr_reader :uri` line to make it refer to the `@uri` instance variable?

Comment: I was adding this line by line from a different computer, so missed the line. I have updated the code

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference `uri` correctly in the `get_status` method as an instance variable or pass it along with the `get_status` method.

Change the following:

```
def get_status
    HEADER = {'Content-Type' => 'application/json' }.freeze
    http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
    request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri, HEADER)

    begin
      res = http.request(request)
    rescue Errno:ECONNREFUSED
      return 'red'
    end

    result = JSON.parse(response.body)
    result['status']
```

To use an instance variable `@uri`, like this:

```
def get_status
    HEADER = {'Content-Type' => 'application/json' }.freeze
    http = Net::HTTP.new(@uri.host, @uri.port)
    request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(@uri.request_uri, HEADER)

    begin
      res = http.request(request)
    rescue Errno:ECONNREFUSED
      return 'red'
    end

    result = JSON.parse(response.body)
    result['status']
```

Or you can pass it along as a method parameter. In that case, change this:

```
 def wait
    status = get_status
    until VALID_STATUS.include? status
      puts 'Still waiting ...'
      sleep 5
      status = get_status
 
  def get_status
    HEADER = {'Content-Type' => 'application/json' }.freeze
    http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
    request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri, HEADER)

    begin
      res = http.request(request)
    rescue Errno:ECONNREFUSED
      return 'red'
    end

    result = JSON.parse(response.body)
    result['status']
```

to this:

```
 def wait
    status = get_status(@uri)
    until VALID_STATUS.include? status
      puts 'Still waiting ...'
      sleep 5
      status = get_status(@uri)
 
  def get_status(uri)
    HEADER = {'Content-Type' => 'application/json' }.freeze
    http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
    request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri, HEADER)

    begin
      res = http.request(request)
    rescue Errno:ECONNREFUSED
      return 'red'
    end

    result = JSON.parse(response.body)
    result['status']
```

Comment: Thanks for the extensive answer. This issue would create a NameError however. My code was unfortunately incompletely as I copied it line by line and I missed adding `attr_reader :uri` in the private section. I have updated the code with the missing line.